# Large, sparse list of lists giving MemoryError when calling np.array(data)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large matrix of `0`s and `1`s, that is mostly `0`s.  It is initially stored as a list of `25 thousand` other lists, each of which are about 2000 ints long.

I am trying to put these into a numpy array, which is what another piece of my program takes.  So I run `training_data = np.array(data)`, but this returns a `MemoryError`

Why is this happening?  I'm assuming it is too much memory for the program to handle (which is surprising to me..), but if so, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (short) integer takes two bytes to store. You want 25,000 lists, each with 2,000 integers; that gives

```
25000*2000*2/1000000 = 100 MB
```

This works fine on my computer (4GB RAM):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.zeros((25000,2000),dtype=int)
```

Are you able to instantiate the above matrix of zeros?

Are you reading the file into a Python list of lists and then converting that to a numpy array? That's a bad idea; it will at least double the memory requirements. What is the file format of your data?

For sparse matrices [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) provides various alternative datatypes which will be much more efficient.

---

EDIT: responding to the OP's comment.

> I have 25000 instances of some other class, each of which returns a list of length about 2000. I want to put all of these lists returned into the `np.array`.

Well, you're somehow going over 8GB! To solve this, don't do all this manipulation in memory. Write the data to disk a class at a time, then delete the instances and read in the file from numpy.

First do

```
with open(..., "wb") as f:
    f = csv.writer(f)
    for instance in instances:
        f.writerow(instance.data)
```

This will write all your data into a large-ish CSV file. Then, you can just use [`np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt):

```
numpy.loadtxt(open(..., "rb"), delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Way more than 100 MB :)  I have 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: To your next edit, I have 25000 instances of some other class, each of which returns a list of length about 2000.  I want to put all of these lists returned into the np.array

Comment: @zebra: wow -- you're going over 8GB! That's impressive :o. I'll edit (again).